# How to run code every X second with Timer in Android

Tags: android, kotlin

In my application I want run code every 20sec!
I write below codes, But run code every 1 mills instead of 20sec !!!

My codes :

```
private fun callLoopApi() {
    timerApi.scheduleAtFixedRate(object : TimerTask() {
        override fun run() {
            CoroutineScope(Main).launch {
                presenter.callApi(teamId)
                Log.e("TimerLog", "Show")
            }
        }
    }, 0, 20000)
}
```

**My Logcat :**

```
2022-02-10 22:09:12.710 5502-5502/my.app E/TimerLog: Show
2022-02-10 22:09:13.194 5502-5502/my.app E/TimerLog: Show
2022-02-10 22:09:13.679 5502-5502/my.app E/TimerLog: Show
2022-02-10 22:09:14.079 5502-5502/my.app E/TimerLog: Show
2022-02-10 22:09:14.427 5502-5502/my.app E/TimerLog: Show
2022-02-10 22:09:14.759 5502-5502/my.app E/TimerLog: Show
2022-02-10 22:09:15.143 5502-5502/my.app E/TimerLog: Show
```

Why not call API every 20 sec?

How can I fix it?

Comment: What happens if you move `Log.e("TimerLog", "Show")` out side of `CoroutineScope(Main).launch` ?

Comment: What is `timerApi`? object of `Timer()`?

Comment: @AndroidGeek yes my friends. `timerApi` is object of `Timer()` . can you help me? please